# Don't create field in database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I hava code like below. It creates a field in database and show in another places. I would like to block create a database field if message field is not exit. Rest fields are taken from system. What is wrong in my code.

```
$delivery->comments_buro()->create([
        'name' => auth()->user()->firstname,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'message' => $request['repair_report_buro'],
        'icon' => 'fa fa-commenting-o',
        'style' => $position->style,
]);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: validation is thing you're looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: I thing yes but I put only field "message", rests are automatically. I would like to block create a database field if this field "message" doesn't exits. I don't know how I can validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need Laravel Validations for that. Please read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

For example:

```php
//controller
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'message' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //do validation error handling here
    }

    // create new row in database.

}
```

Comment: Ok, but I have many fields which could be update. I would like that system does nothing if there is nothing in "message". I can't setup "message" as required because it could be also empty. It's not necessary to update this field every time.

Comment: I have updated some time "message" but I can also updated another fields. There is decribe problem with car in "message" field or decribe what client want. I can't put required to "message" field.

Comment: You need to have something distinguishing if that's an update or create. If it's an `update` you'll remove `required` from validations and if it's `create` you add it back.

Comment: It must be create because when I open client's order "message" is empty. There is nothing. I would like to do nothing with it if I put nothing to this field.

Comment: I used this code:

`if($request->filled('repair_report_buro')){
   $delivery->comments_buro()->create([
        'name' => auth()->user()->firstname,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'message' => $request['repair_report_buro'],
        'icon' => 'fa fa-commenting-o',
        'style' => $position->style,
    ]);
}`

but I have mistake:
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method filled does not exist.

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: `filled()` method was introduced in `Laravel 5.5`

Answer (score 0):

I have a right code. It works with it. I close this question. The right code is:

`if(isset($request['repair_report_buro']) && !empty($request['repair_report_buro'])){
            $delivery->comments_buro()->create([
                'name' => auth()->user()->firstname,
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'message' => $request['repair_report_buro'],
                'icon' => 'fa fa-commenting-o',
                'style' => $position->style,
            ]);
        }`